# Adding binding View feature to adapter on kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, binding

I am trying to implement binding on the project but ItemView is becoming reddish.
Here is code.

```
class RecyclerviewAdapter:RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerviewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    class ViewHolder(binding: ItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
    

    @SuppressLint("SuspiciousIndentation")
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val inflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val view= DataBindingUtil.inflate<**ItemBinding**>(inflater, R.layout.item,parent,false)
            return  ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

I wanna to make the recyclerView work with binding feature.

Comment: Why are you suppressing "SuspiciousIndentation" and using unusual indentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the proper syntax.

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val binding = ItemBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(binding)
}
```

You probably want to make `binding` a `val` in the ViewHolder constructor so you can access it in `onBindViewHolder`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
lateinit var binding: ItemBinding

class ViewHolder(binding: ItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item, container, false)
    binding = ItemBinding.bind(view)

    return  ViewHolder(binding.root)
}
```

Comment: The binding shouldn't be kept in an adapter class-level property because there will be many bindings, one for each view holder created.

Comment: In case of multiple viewholders you can create this binding generic type, with conditional logic and casting.

Comment: I don’t mean multiple ViewHolder classes, I mean instances. I’m saying that `binding` property shouldn’t exist there.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. By removing binding property and Just use val in constructor will solve this problem.